# Add text to the text field that appears after clicking on button

Tags: excel, vba

I use a website to submit medication errors.

Till now, I added text from an Excel spreadsheet.

I discovered how to click on a button. After clicking on the button, a new text field appears in which I wish to enter text.

```vb
Sub MERF()

  Dim IE As Object
  Dim doc As HTMLDocument
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.navigate "https://portal.spsc.gov.sa/MEH/Default.aspx?Id=386"
  
  Do While IE.Busy
     Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
  Loop
  
  Set doc = IE.document

  'IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Mr_Txt").Value = "very cute"
  doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Event_Date_Txt").Value = Sheet1.Range("F34").Value
  doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Wasfaty_Chk_1").Click
  doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Wasfaty_Other").Value = "OASIS prescription"
  doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Mr_Txt").Value = Sheet1.Range("B34").Value
  doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Event_Desc_Txt").Value = Sheet1.Range("M34").Value
  doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtReporterComment").Value = Sheet1.Range("Q34").Value
  doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Reporter_Name_Txt").Value = "name"
  doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Reporter_Email_Txt").Value = "mail"
  doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Reporter_Mobile_Txt").Value = "xx"

End Sub
```

It blocks here:

```
doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Wasfaty_Chk_1").Click  
doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Wasfaty_Other").Value = "OASIS prescription"
```

I tried using Wait and Loop.

Answer (score 1):

That's it.
I found a solution by adding Wait.

I added this:

```
Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05")
doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Wasfaty_Other").Value = Sheet1.Range("T34").Value
```